# How to create Chosen-Selects with WTForms?

Tags: python, jquery-chosen, flask-wtforms, wtforms

How can I create a form with [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in which the `<select>` elements are [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)-Selects?

I tried [this](https://www.julo.ch/blog/wtforms-chosen/) approach, but it seems outdated.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was the following:

```py
from wtforms import SelectField, SelectMultipleField


def _add_chosen_class(kwargs):
    '''
    Add the class 'chosen-select' to the HTML elements, keeping any
    other specified render parameters or other classes.
    '''
    if 'render_kw' in kwargs:
        if 'class' in kwargs['render_kw']:
            kwargs['render_kw']['class'] += ' chosen-select'
        else:
            kwargs['render_kw']['class'] = 'chosen-select'
    else:
        kwargs['render_kw'] = {'class': 'chosen-select'}


class ChosenSelectField(SelectField):
    '''A select field rendered with chosen'''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _add_chosen_class(kwargs)
        super(ChosenSelectField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class ChosenSelectMultipleField(SelectMultipleField):
    '''A multiple-select field rendered with chosen'''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _add_chosen_class(kwargs)
        super(ChosenSelectMultipleField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can declare `ChosenSelect[Multiple]Field`s in your forms.

On the Javascript side you have to do the regular chosen spiel—include `chosen.min.js` and run (assuming jQuery)

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({/* chosen-config here */})
```

Note:
This approach will not show any error popups on submit if your field is required, because chosen hides the original `<select>`. You will have to take care of that some other way (maybe CSS).

Comment: I tried following this and wasn't able to get it to work - it just renders a regular select field. Any chance you could post a minimum working example?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the [blog example](https://www.julo.ch/blog/wtforms-chosen/) to work by changing a few things.  Note that this does require [jquery](https://jquery.com/) and [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) javascript imports to the page.  I was using the `SelectMultipleField` for multiple, but it may need to be `SelectField` if you're doing a single select.

```py
from markupsafe import Markup
from wtforms.widgets import Select

class ChosenSelect(Select):
    def __init__(self, multiple=False, renderer=None, options={}):
        """
        Initiate the widget. This offers you two general options.
        First off it allows you to configure the ChosenSelect to
        allow multiple options and it allows you to pass options
        to the chosen select (this will produce a json object)
        that chosen will get passed as configuration.

            :param multiple: whether this is a multiple select
                (default to `False`)
            :param renderer: If you do not want to use the default
                select renderer, you can pass a function that will
                get the field and options as arguments so that
                you can customize the rendering.
            :param options: a dictionary of options that will
                influence the chosen behavior. If no options are
                given `width: 100%` will be set.
        """
        super(ChosenSelect, self).__init__(multiple=multiple)
        self.renderer = renderer
        options.setdefault("width", "100%")
        self.options = options

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        """
        Render the actual select.

            :param field: the field to render
            :param **kwargs: options to pass to the rendering
                (i.e. class, data-* and so on)

        This will render the select as is and attach a chosen
        initiator script for the given id afterwards considering
        the options set up in the beginning.
        """
        kwargs.setdefault("id", field.id)
        # currently chosen does not reflect the readonly attribute
        # we compensate for that by automatically setting disabled,
        # if readonly if given
        # https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/67
        if kwargs.get("readonly"):
            kwargs["disabled"] = "disabled"
        html = []
        # render the select
        if self.renderer:
            html.append(self.renderer(self, field, **kwargs))
        else:
            html.append(super(ChosenSelect, self).__call__(field, **kwargs))
        # attach the chosen initiation with options
        html.append(
            '<script>$("#%s").chosen(%s);</script>\n'
            % (kwargs["id"], json.dumps(self.options))
        )
        # return the HTML (as safe markup)
        return Markup("\n".join(html))
```

```py
from wtforms import Form, SelectMultipleField

class ExampleForm(Form):
    example = SelectMultipleField("Example", choices=[("1", "1"), ("2", "2")], widget=ChosenSelect(multiple=True))
```